# How to access current route name reactively in Vue Composition API in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

How can I access **current route name**, reactively, with **Vue Router** using **Vue Composition API** in **Vue 3 with TypeScript**?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here are examples using **Vue 3.0** and **Vue Router v4.0.0-beta.12** with **Composition API** syntax:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, computed, watch } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyCoolComponent',
  setup() {
    const route = useRoute();
    
    console.debug(`current route name on component setup init: ${route.name}`);

    // You could use computed property which re-evaluates on route name updates
    // const routeName = computed(() => route.name);

    // You can watch the property for triggering some other action on change
    watch(() => route.name, () => {
      console.debug(`MyCoolComponent - watch route.name changed to ${route.name}`);
      // Do something here...

    // Optionally you can set immediate: true config for the watcher to run on init
    //}, { immediate: true });
    });
    
    return { route };
  },
});
</script>

<template>
  <p>Current route name: {{ route.name }}</p>
</template>
```

Or by using the currently experimental **Script Setup syntax**, [SFC Composition API Syntax Sugar](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/sfc-improvements/active-rfcs/0000-sfc-script-setup.md), for **Composition API**:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { computed, watch } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';

export const name = 'MyCoolComponent';

export const route = useRoute();
    
console.debug(`current route name on component setup init: ${route.name}`);

// You could use computed property which re-evaluates on route name updates
//export const routeName = computed(() => route.name);

// You can watch the property for triggering some other action on change
watch(() => route.name, () => {
  console.debug(`MyCoolComponent - watch route.name changed to ${route.name}`);
  // Do something here...

  // Optionally you can set immediate: true config for the watcher to run on init
//}, { immediate: true });
});
</script>

<template>
  <p>Current route name: {{ route.name }}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: Can't `export` in <script setup...>

Answer (score 3):

Here's my example which is for watching route params instead. This question comes up when generally searching for how to watch route params in Vue 3.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import axios from 'axios'
import { ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue'
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const route = useRoute()
const page = ref<any>({})

const fetchPage = async () => {
    console.log('route', route.params)
    const { data } = await axios.get(
        `/api/${route.params.locale}/pages/${route.params.slug}`,
        {
            params: {
                include: 'sections,documents,courses',
            },
        }
    )

    page.value = data.data
}

onMounted(() => {
    fetchPage()
})

watch(() => route.params.slug, fetchPage)
</script>
```

In my example, `route.name` doesn't change but `route.params.slug` changes.

Comment: I was making assumptions about the route _name_ being automatically set, but it wasn't.  But _path_ is being set within the RouteRecordRaw array.  So watching _path_ worked. BTW, no luck with _route.params.slug_

Comment: Sorry, `slug` is the route param in my application. It comes from the vue-router file such as path `/something/:slug`. Double check my code where I put `console.log('route', route.params)`. You can see yours there. Note the import of `useRoute`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method instead:

```
    watch(
    route.params,
    () => {
      console.log(route.params.name);
    },
    {deep: true, immediate: true,}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Mohammad Hosseini's answer didn't work for me. I have to,

```
watch(
  () => $route.params,
  () => {
    console.log(" $route.params:", $route.params);
  }
);
```