# What is the syntax for watch in the vue 3 composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63800832/1497720
```

Typical watch syntax is `watch(<variable>, <function to handle>)`
but in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63800832/1497720

we have

```
watch(() => route.name, () => {
  console.debug(`MyCoolComponent - watch route.name changed to ${route.name}`);
  // Do something here...

  // Optionally you can set immediate: true config for the watcher to run on init
//}, { immediate: true });
});
```

Can someone explain what's the syntax means?

Answer (score 1):

The full syntax of a watch helper is :

```js
watch(param1,param2,param3)
```

**param1** could be a `ref` data or a getter function that returns another reactive data (prop, computed or reactive ...)

**param2** is the callback handler that takes two parameters the new value and the old one

**param3** is the watch options like `{immediate:true,deep:true}` which is optional

Comment: What's the incentive for using a getter function, if can simply use the return value?

Comment: using a simple variable works only with `ref` data, for other data you should use a getter function to trigger the watcher

Answer (score 0):

That's just another way of using vm.$watch API, please refer to the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch)

The key point to take away here is that you can not only watch a data or a computed property, but also an expression. The expression only accepts dot-delimited paths. For more complex expressions, use a function instead.

This is an example:

```
vm.$watch(
  function () {
    // every time the expression `this.a + this.b` yields a different result,
    // the handler will be called. It's as if we were watching a computed
    // property without defining the computed property itself
    return this.a + this.b
  },
  function (newVal, oldVal) {
    // do something
  }
)
```

So in your example above, it can simplify to this piece of code below:

```
watch('route.name', () => {
  console.debug(`MyCoolComponent - watch route.name changed to ${route.name}`);
  // Do something here...

  // Optionally you can set immediate: true config for the watcher to run on init
//}, { immediate: true });
})
```